# How can I combine these 3 queries to achieve my desired, formatted, result

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 queries that run at the same time in order to get 3 different lists of profiles. It's cacheable data for the same page, so I'd like to do it all in a single query. This is my single biggest hurdle when using Postgres. Can someone help me begin understanding the process of combining queries and formatting?

Here are the queries:

- Retrieves the 10 users with the sum highest loan balance

  ```
  select user_loans.user_id,
    sum(user_loans.balance) as total_balance,
    sum(user_loans.origination_principal_amount) as origination_principal_amount,
    mode() within group (order by user_profiles.first_name) as first_name,
    mode() within group (order by user_profiles.last_name) as last_name,
    mode() within group (order by user_profiles.city) as city,
    mode() within group (order by user_profiles.state) as state
  from user_loans
  join user_profiles on user_loans.user_id = user_profiles.user_id
  group by user_loans.user_id
  order by total_balance desc
  limit 10;
  ```
- Retrieves the 10 newest users with a loan added

  ```
  select user_loans.user_id,
    user_profiles.created_at,
    sum(user_loans.balance) as total_balance,
    sum(user_loans.origination_principal_amount) as origination_principal_amount,
    mode() within group (order by user_profiles.first_name) as first_name,
    mode() within group (order by user_profiles.last_name) as last_name,
    mode() within group (order by user_profiles.city) as city,
    mode() within group (order by user_profiles.state) as state
  from user_loans 
  join user_profiles on user_loans.user_id = user_profiles.user_id 
  group by user_loans.user_id, user_profiles.created_at
  order by user_profiles.created_at desc
  limit 10;
  ```
- Retrieves the 10 newest users with a loan added and marked as a featured profile

  ```
  select user_loans.user_id,
    user_profiles.created_at,
    sum(user_loans.balance) as total_balance,
    sum(user_loans.origination_principal_amount) as origination_principal_amount,
    mode() within group (order by user_profiles.first_name) as first_name,
    mode() within group (order by user_profiles.last_name) as last_name,
    mode() within group (order by user_profiles.city) as city,
    mode() within group (order by user_profiles.state) as state
  from user_loans 
  join user_profiles on user_loans.user_id = user_profiles.user_id
  where user_profiles.featured = true
  group by user_loans.user_id, user_profiles.created_at
  order by user_profiles.created_at
  limit 10;
  ```

They all work as expected individually, but I prefer if I could combine them, and format them so that my end result is:

```
most_loans             | newest                 | featured
-----------------------+------------------------+-----------------------
[results_from_query#1] | [results_from_query#2] | [results_from_query#3]
```

I want the results_from_query to be an array of objects created by the results of the queries mentioned above.

I tried using a combination of `json_agg` and `json_build_object` but I got errors about having nested aggregate functions. I'm stumped on where to go from here.

At this point I'm ok not formatting so specifically. I can handle that programatically. If I could just get the results of the three queries combined that would be a good starting point for me. They all have the same columns.

So I'm trying `union`

```
(select user_loans.user_id,
       user_profiles.created_at,
       sum(user_loans.balance) as total_balance,
       sum(user_loans.origination_principal_amount) as origination_principal_amount,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.first_name) as first_name,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.last_name) as last_name,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.city) as city,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.state) as state,
       'top' as type
from user_loans
join user_profiles on user_loans.user_id = user_profiles.user_id
group by user_loans.user_id, user_profiles.created_at
order by total_balance desc
limit 10)
union all
(select user_loans.user_id,
       user_profiles.created_at,
       sum(user_loans.balance) as total_balance,
       sum(user_loans.origination_principal_amount) as origination_principal_amount,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.first_name) as first_name,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.last_name) as last_name,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.city) as city,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.state) as state,
       'newest' as type
from user_loans 
join user_profiles on user_loans.user_id = user_profiles.user_id 
group by user_loans.user_id, user_profiles.created_at
order by user_profiles.created_at desc
limit 10)
union all
(select user_loans.user_id,
       user_profiles.created_at,
       sum(user_loans.balance) as total_balance,
       sum(user_loans.origination_principal_amount) as origination_principal_amount,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.first_name) as first_name,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.last_name) as last_name,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.city) as city,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.state) as state,
       'featured' as type
from user_loans 
join user_profiles on user_loans.user_id = user_profiles.user_id
where user_profiles.featured = true
group by user_loans.user_id, user_profiles.created_at
order by user_profiles.created_at
limit 10)
```

Even closer. I have all the queries combined, and a column indicating which query the row came from. This is enough where I can do the formatting programmatically. I'm curious if I can group by `type` and use `json_agg` and `json_build_object` at this point to achieve my original goal.

---

I think I'll end with this. It's not 100% what I wanted but it accomplishes the same end goal. A single query that returns 3 arrays with results. With this approach they are 3 separate rows with a single value, the array of objects. Not sure how I can combine this into a single row with named columns, but close enough.

```
SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(all_featured)) as results
from
((select user_loans.user_id,
       user_profiles.created_at,
       sum(user_loans.balance) as total_balance,
       sum(user_loans.origination_principal_amount) as origination_principal_amount,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.first_name) as first_name,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.last_name) as last_name,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.city) as city,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.state) as state,
       'top' as type
from user_loans
join user_profiles on user_loans.user_id = user_profiles.user_id
group by user_loans.user_id, user_profiles.created_at
order by total_balance desc
limit 10)
union all
(select user_loans.user_id,
       user_profiles.created_at,
       sum(user_loans.balance) as total_balance,
       sum(user_loans.origination_principal_amount) as origination_principal_amount,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.first_name) as first_name,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.last_name) as last_name,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.city) as city,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.state) as state,
       'newest' as type
from user_loans 
join user_profiles on user_loans.user_id = user_profiles.user_id 
group by user_loans.user_id, user_profiles.created_at
order by user_profiles.created_at desc
limit 10)
union all
(select user_loans.user_id,
       user_profiles.created_at,
       sum(user_loans.balance) as total_balance,
       sum(user_loans.origination_principal_amount) as origination_principal_amount,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.first_name) as first_name,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.last_name) as last_name,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.city) as city,
       mode() within group (order by user_profiles.state) as state,
       'featured' as type
from user_loans 
join user_profiles on user_loans.user_id = user_profiles.user_id
where user_profiles.featured = true
group by user_loans.user_id, user_profiles.created_at
order by user_profiles.created_at
limit 10)) as all_featured
group by type
```

Comment: Please show us what the actual expected output table looks like.  It is not clear from your current sample output what you want here.

Comment: If you look at the bottom I show what I want my end result to be. It's just a single row with 3 specifically named columns. The result for each column is the result from the queries mentioned above. And the results should be an array of objects. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: It doesn't make sense, because each of the three queries appears to return _ten_ records, yet your expected output is just a single row.

Comment: Right, so the single row will contain arrays of objects.

Comment: So what is the rule to put fields side by side. There is no warranty for the first row on query 1 be related to first row of query 2 and yet you want it side by side?

Comment: I'm not sure Juan, my expertise isn't in sql so I'm trying to learn the terminology and everything as I go. The queries all return a curated list of user_profiles with some additional information from user_loans. Otherwise, the columns have nothing in common. No shared user or anything like that. I might be going about this the wrong way, but I think it should be possible. I've made other complex queries using `json_agg` and `json_build_object` to append columns to rows.

Comment: Why don't you use a union?

Comment: Trying to get union to work atm. I'll edit with what I'm trying and the error in getting.

Comment: Show us some sample data. Simplify your queries. We don't need those SUM, JOINS, just 3 generic tables and how would looks after result. That way we can be more precise on what **combine** means for you

Comment: Can you give me tips on simplifying? Or link me to resources. I have a feeling I can reuse the complex select that I'm doing 3 times, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Try something like [**THIS**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=132c746cdb8196a50ad934db865f9ddb) 3 queries with different result everything else seem irrelevant for me right now. You also can use https://www.generatedata.com/#t1 to get some invented data to be more related to your problem. But the idea is keep it simple. How you calculate the data isn't important you want to focus on how combine it.

Comment: BTW,  On Your query 2 and 3 you shouldn't `GROUP BY user_profiles.created_at`  I don't think you have multiple date for user creation. So doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You can convert 3 rows into one using PIVOT

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just use a [WITH query](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), to combine them without changing them.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about WITH. Looks like this will combine all the rows from the 3 queries into one big list. I need a way to indicate the separation so I can split up the three lists on the frontend. Is there a way I can at least add a column with a key indicating which of the 3 lists the row belongs to?

Answer (score -1):

Modifying the first answer:

```
SELECT user_id,
       q1.total_balance, ...,
       q2.total_balance, ...,
       q3.total_balance, ...,
FROM ((/* your first query */) AS q1,
   (/* your second query */) AS q2,
   (/* your third query */) AS q3
WHERE q1.key = q2.key
AND q1.key = q3.key
```

This should do the job.